# Filling interior door trim gap

Tags: drywall, doors, trim, remodeling, gap

The doors were installed at the same time as the paneling.  Now, however, there is 1/2" drywall, and if I try to install the trim around the doors, there's a huge gap between the door frame and the trim (see photo).

[image: drywall vs trim]

All the doors are similar in disposition; they all will have about a 1/2" gap (some nominally less, but still significant).  I'm trying to get away with not having to pull out the door frames, but rather just filling the gap somehow.  Any ideas or guidance are very much appreciated.

Comment: Trim should be added on both sides and top of the door frame to cover that gap

Comment: Do you have this on both sides of the door? What you are looking to make is a [jamb extension](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/install-extension-jamb-door-21419.html). Where it gets tricky is if you have to extend the "hinge" side of the door.

Answer (score 2):

Find some cheap 1/2"x (something like 1" -- could be 3/4; could probably be as big as 1-1/4). Nail that to the jamb first. (1/4" reveal is typical.) Then put door casing on top of that. Could be dead flush, or could have a slight reveal of its own.

Pro tip: too small a reveal (like, 1/8") is hard to do, because subtle differences in width can be seen easily. A bit bigger, and your 32nds disappear.

Comment: Parting bead as it is typically called measures 1/2"X 3/4", that should do the trick. Fasten it in place 1/4" back from the opening as mentioned above. This will get you past going beside the hinges where they occur.